# XML parsing with attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xsd, xml-attribute

I want know the xml parsing if the data have attributes at the middle of the tag..
that means,

```
<quran>
 <sura index="1" name="الفاتحة">
  <aya index="1" text="بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم" />
  <aya index="2" text="الحمد لله رب العالمين" />
  <aya index="3" text="الرحمن الرحيم" />
  <aya index="4" text="مالك يوم الدين" />
  <aya index="5" text="إياك نعبد وإياك نستعين" />
 </sura>
 <sura index="2" name="البقرة">
  <aya index="1" text="الم" bismillah="بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم" />
  <aya index="2" text="ذلك الكتاب لا ريب ۛ فيه ۛ هدى للمتقين" />
  <aya index="3" text="الذين يؤمنون بالغيب ويقيمون الصلاة ومما رزقناهم ينفقون" />
  <aya index="4" text="والذين يؤمنون بما أنزل إليك وما أنزل من قبلك وبالآخرة هم يوقنون" />
  <aya index="5" text="أولئك على هدى من ربهم ۖ وأولئك هم المفلحون" />
  <aya index="6" text="إن الذين كفروا سواء عليهم أأنذرتهم أم لم تنذرهم لا يؤمنون" />
  </sura>
<sura index="3" name="البقرة">
  <aya index="1" text="الم" bismillah="بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم" />
  <aya index="2" text="ذلك الكتاب لا ريب ۛ فيه ۛ هدى للمتقين" />
  <aya index="3" text="الذين يؤمنون بالغيب ويقيمون الصلاة ومما رزقناهم ينفقون" />
  <aya index="4" text="والذين يؤمنون بما أنزل إليك وما أنزل من قبلك وبالآخرة هم يوقنون" />
  <aya index="5" text="أولئك على هدى من ربهم ۖ وأولئك هم المفلحون" />
  <aya index="6" text="إن الذين كفروا سواء عليهم أأنذرتهم أم لم تنذرهم لا يؤمنون" />
  </sura>
</quran>
```

i want to get that data into 2 or 3 arrays or in dictionaries..
How it is possible?

Comment: First make google as your friend check some initial tutorial  then if you have any problem then you can ask here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask.  Please post an example of some XML you are trying to parse.